# Is it possible use macros with LatexSwiftUI like in MathJax?

Tags: swiftui, latex, mathjax

I want to use existing articles written in Latex in an iOS App written in SwiftUI.
However in the LaTeX sources lots of macros are defined with
\def, \newcommand and \renewcommand.
As I learned, these macros can be used in MathJax.
Because LatexSwiftUI is based on MathJax, I am wondering if it were not possible to use these macros in LatexSwift too. However, I didn't find any hint how to do so.
Can somebody give an example?

Comment: Did you check with the developers of LatexSwiftUI?